# How do i make a login signup system in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, replit

im trying to write code in python that basically its so that in the terminal you input whether you want to signup or log in if you already signed up
i cant really figure out how to make it so that the signup input gets stored in a dictionary and then later when you try to enter the username and password it makes sure its the same one from the signup feature
thanks in advance

so far ive tried

```
accounts = {"user":"password", "user2":"password2"}
login_or_signup = input("Login or signup? ")
if login_or_signup.upper() == 'LOGIN':
    username = input("Enter your username: ")
    if username in list(accounts.keys()):
        password = input("Enter your password: ")
        if password in list(accounts.values()):
            print("Logged in successfully.")
        else:
            print("Account credentials do not match.")
    else:
        print("Account not found.")
elif login_or_signup.upper() == "SIGNUP":
    username = input("Enter your username: ")
    password = input("Enter your password: ")
    accounts.update({user,password})
```

but im getting an error

Comment: What error? Look at [ask]

Comment: you are just checking that password is somewhere in the dictionary values, but not that belongs to that specific user. you need to do `if accounts[username] == password`. Also, no need to cast `accounts.keys()` into a list

Comment: im trying to make it so that it both adds the username and password to a list or dictionary when you write signup in the terminal, and then when you do login in the terminal it checks if the information you used to signup matches

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your last line, it should be `username` instead of `user`. Also `:` instead of `,`

```
accounts.update({username: password})
```

That will make your program not fail in both options.

However, first, you are not checking properly the password, you need to grab the user and check if the password corresponds to the user in your dictionary.

Additionally, your program will finish right after you set up your new signup. You can add a `while True` loop at the top and `break` accordingly in the condition you would like to do so ([example](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/python-keep-asking-for-user-input-until-valid#:%7E:text=To%20keep%20asking%20for%20user,break%20out%20of%20the%20loop.))

Answer (score 0):

You should check if input password, matches the input username.

```
accounts = {"user": "password", "user2": "password2"}
login_or_signup = input("Login or signup? ")

while True:
    if login_or_signup.upper() == 'LOGIN':
        username = input("Enter your username: ")
        if username in accounts:
            password = input("Enter your password: ")
            if accounts[username] == password:
                print("Logged in successfully.")
            else:
                print("Account credentials do not match.")
        else:
            print("Account not found.")
    elif login_or_signup.upper() == "SIGNUP":
        username = input("Enter your username: ")
        password = input("Enter your password: ")
        accounts[username] = password
```